# Ajax call handle 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to handle 404 error that developers tools / javascript console doesn't show error.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com",
    datatype: "xml",
    error:
        function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + '\n'+ errorThrown);
        },
    success: 
        function(xml) {
            /* BL for xml */        
        }
});
```

So when url is not found i get error in developer tools, is any way to hide it

Comment: just dont alert the error out.

Comment: look there ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can catch `404` error status code like this and handle it

```
           error:
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 if(jqXHR.status == 404)                       
                  { 
                    // handle 404 error
                  }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

add a

```
    statusCode:{
404:function(){
                 $("#messageError").html("Yor error");
              },      
           },
```